# ServiceKnownType client side issue

Tags: c#, wcf, serviceknowntype

Server side:

Service details:

```
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(Helper))]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAppConfigurationManager
{
    [OperationContract]
    object ChangeObjectProperty(object myCustomObject);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AppConfigurationManager : IAppConfigurationManager
{
    public object ChangeObjectProperty(object myCustomObject)
    {
        foreach (Type type in Globals.MyCustomTypes)
        {
            if (type == myCustomObject.GetType())
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo Property in myCustomObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if(Property.Name == "ID")
                    {
                        int oldValue = Convert.ToInt32(Property.GetValue(myCustomObject));
                        Property.SetValue(myCustomObject, oldValue + 1);
                        break;
                    };
                };                    
            }
        }

        return myCustomObject;
    }
}
```

Helper class is used for collecting of KnownTypes:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        Globals.MyCustomTypes = new List<Type>();

        System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type> knownTypes =
            new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Type>();

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\WCF\RuntimeManagement\bin\Debug\RuntimeManagement.dll");

        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.Name.Contains("Customer") || type.Name.Contains("Account"))
            {
                knownTypes.Add(type);
                Globals.MyCustomTypes.Add(type);
            };
        };

        return knownTypes;
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Account
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Customer AccountOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Client side:

Before invoking the service, trying to register KnownTypes at client side also:

```
private void fmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyCustomTypes = new List<Type>();

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\WCF\RuntimeManagement\bin\Debug\RuntimeManagement.dll");

    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (type.Name.Contains("Customer") || type.Name.Contains("Account"))
        {
            MyCustomTypes.Add(type);

            if (type.Name == "Customer")
            {
                CustomerType = type;
            };

            foreach (var operation in Globals.AppConfigMgrClient.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            {
                operation.KnownTypes.Add(type);
            };
        };
    };

    object myCustomerObject = Activator.CreateInstance(CustomerType);

    foreach (PropertyInfo Property in myCustomerObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (Property.Name == "ID")
        {
            Property.SetValue(myCustomerObject, 111);
            break;
        };
    };

    myCustomerObject = Globals.AppConfigMgrClient.ChangeObjectProperty(myCustomerObject);

    foreach (PropertyInfo Property in myCustomerObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (Property.Name == "ID")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Property.GetValue(myCustomerObject).ToString());
            break;
        };
    };
}
```

Got error here:

```
myCustomerObject = Globals.AppConfigMgrClient.ChangeObjectProperty((RuntimeManagement.CatalogManagement.Customer)myCustomerObject);
```

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:myCustomObject. The InnerException message was
>   'Element 'http://tempuri.org/:myCustomObject' contains data from a
>   type that maps to the name 'http://tempuri.org/:Customer'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider using a DataContractResolver or add the type corresponding to
>   'Customer' to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException
>   for more details.

May be long post, hope you got idea what I am trying to do here:

1. Adding `Customer` and `Account` classes to `ServiceKnownType` at server side helper class.
2. On load event of client side, trying to register `KnownTypes` from the same assembly where `Customer` and `Account` exists.
3. Then creating instance of `Customer` type, set it's `ID` property to 111, send it `OperationContract` called `ChangeObjectProperty`. After successful execution, it should increment ID.

Thanks for your time.